# How do I make someone's answer correspond to the total value of the product?

Tags: python, input

I just started learning Python 2 days ago and I created a simple "store" that you can order and the program would tell you the total. But the problem is that I don't know how to make a person's answer to show the total value of the product. As in if person A orders an iPhone, it'll show the price of the iPhone.

I kind of did it but I used the if statements, but I know that this method isn't efficient, as well as if Person B chooses more than 1 product, I don't know how to make a sum of the prices automatically instead of using the if statements, here is my code, thank you!

```
print("Welcome to the Apple Store!")

name = input("What is your name?\n")

print("Hello " + name + ", welcome to the Apple store!\n\n")

products = "iPhone 14 $10,000, Macbook Air $14,000, iPhone 13 $8,000\n"

value = input

iPhone_14 = 10000
Macbook_Air = 14000
iPhone_13 = 8000

a = iPhone_14 + Macbook_Air


order = input("Here is our list of products, what would you want?\n" + products)

if order == "iPhone 14":
    print("Alright " + name + ", your " + order + " will be prepared.\n\n" + "The total amount will be " + str(iPhone_14))

if order == "Macbook Air":
    print("Alright " + name + ", your " + order + " will be prepared.\n\n" + "The total amount will be " + str(Macbook_Air))

if order == "iPhone 13":
    print("Alright " + name + ", your " + order + " will be prepared.\n\n" + "The total amount will be " + str(iPhone_13))

if order == "iPhone 14, Macbook Air":
    print("Alright " + name + ", your " + order + " will be prepared.\n\n" + "The total amount will be " + str(a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a simple solution, I left you some comments inside the code:

```
# you can use a dictionary to store the value of each product
products = {"iPhone_14": 10000, "Macbook_Air": 14000, "iPhone_13": 8000}

# this list will contain the keys of the products you want to add to cart
cart = []

print("Here our list of products {}, what do you want to buy?\nEnter 'stop' when you're done\n".format(list(products.keys())))

stop = False
while not stop:

    order = input("Insert a product:")
    if order == "stop":
        # if the user want to stop entering products, can type "stop" instead of a product
        stop = True
    elif order in products:
        cart.append(order)
    else:
        # if the product entered is not among the products dictionary keys
        print("Product {} is not available".format(order))

print("\nThis is your cart:")
total = 0
for elem in cart:
    print("Product {} ({}$)".format(elem, products[elem]))
    total += products[elem]

print("Your total is {}$".format(total))
```

Example:

```bash
Here our list of products ['iPhone_14', 'Macbook_Air', 'iPhone_13'], what do you want to buy?
Enter 'stop' when you're done
    
Insert a product:Macbook_Air
Insert a product:iPhone_14
Insert a product:stop
This is your cart:
Product Macbook_Air (14000$)
Product iPhone_14 (10000$)
Your total is 24000$
```